# How to get the perticular string

Tags: postgresql

I have a string like this `'ramesh//ram/123.jpeg'`.
Here i want get `'123.jpeg'`.

How will i use position and substring to get this?

Comment: will all your files be in the /ram folder?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the regex variant of `substring`, matching all characters after the last `'/'`:

```
SELECT substring('ramesh//ram/123.jpeg' FROM '[^/]*$')
```

I don't think there's any easy way to get the *last* position of a character. The closest you can get without a regular expression is probably:

```
SELECT a[array_length(a,1)] FROM string_to_array('ramesh//ram/123.jpeg', '/') a;
```